# Service gets disconnected when started from UI thread

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

When i try to bind service from UI thread , my BluetoothLeService becomes null after sometime. mBlutoothLeService is set properly but after executing multiple gattUpdateReceiver it becomes null.

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
                               new   BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
            byte[] scanRecord) {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (device != null && device.getName() != null) {
                    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), BluetoothLeService.class);
                    getActivity().bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

                }
        });
    }
};


private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName,
            IBinder service) {
        Log.e(TAG, "service connected");

        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service)
                .getService();

        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        Log.e(TAG, "service disconnected");
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }


};
```

I tried binding service using handler (new Handler(getActivity().getMainLooper())) but still mBluetoothLeService becomes null.
But when I start bind service in OnCreate() of new fragment it works without any issue. Is it something to do with UI thread?

Comment: You should communicate with a Services from UI thread only

Answer (score 0):

You may not get your current activity using `getActivity()` with this code in a Runnable ---

```
@Override
public void run() {

if (device != null && device.getName() != null) {
   Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), BluetoothLeService.class);
   getActivity().bindService(gattServiceIntent, 
   mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

   }
});
```

So idea is to use the bind service at `onCreate()`.

However, you can get the activity in asyntask with ---

```
class MyClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private Activity currentActivity;

        public MyClass(Activity activity) {
            currentActivity = activity;
        }

@Override
    public void run() {

    if (device != null && device.getName() != null) {
       Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(currentActivity, BluetoothLeService.class);
       getActivity().bindService(gattServiceIntent, 
       mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

       }
    });
}
```